# ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8 for import spacy

Tags: python, macos, utf-8, spacy

when I import spacy (python) on mac, give me ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
I find answer that said to me: he said:
I write commend below

```
$ .bash_profile
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I find answer for that :
when I write `~/.bash_profile` give me :

```
-bash: /Users/apple/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

but I should write :

```
$ sudo Console ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
$ sudo edit ~/.bash_profile
```

and continue :

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and run ....

Comment: what about in ubuntu?